# Java: Compareable<List<T extends Compareable<T>>>

Tags: java, comparable

Is there any `Compareable<Collection<T extends Compareable<T>>>` implementation in Java (which behaves as C++'s `std::list<T>::operator<()` or `std::set<T>::operator<()`)?

---

Edit: `Comparator` would make more sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I am aware of, but it shouldn't be too difficult to write.

```
compareTo(Collection<T> other) {
    Iterator<T> i1 = this.iterator();
    Iterator<T> i2 = other.iterator();
    while(i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
        int c = i1.next().compareTo(i2.next());
        if(c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    if(i1.hasNext()){
        return 1;
    } else if(i2.hasNext()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should point out that this only works for ordered collections.  It won't work for collections based on hash tables for example because the order of the elements returned by a hash table's iterator depends on the sequence of operations that constructed the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about those C++ operators you mention, but I'm *assuming* what you want is a comparator that compares the collections lexicographically.

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has this through its excellent `Ordering` class: [Ordering.lexicographical()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#lexicographical%28%29)

> Returns a new ordering which sorts iterables by comparing corresponding elements pairwise until a nonzero result is found; imposes "dictionary order". If the end of one iterable is reached, but not the other, the shorter iterable is considered to be less than the longer one. For example, a lexicographical natural ordering over integers considers `[] < [1] < [1, 1] < [1, 2] < [2]`.

Say you wanted to order a `List<List<String>>` based on `String`'s natural order:

```
List<List<String>> lists = ...; 
Ordering<Iterable<String>> comparator = Ordering.natural().lexicographical();
Collections.sort(lists, comparator);
```

Given that this is part of the `Ordering` class, you get its full power as well, including the ability to use it with any arbitrary comparator:

```
/*
 * This comparator will use a case insensitive comparison of individual
 * strings in determining the ordering.
 */
Ordering<Iterable<String>> comparator =
    Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).lexicographical();

/*
 * This comparator uses a Function<Foo, Long> (Foo.GET_ID) to compare the IDs
 * of Foo instances.
 */
Ordering<Iterable<Foo>> comparator = 
     Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Foo.GET_ID).lexicographical();
```